# Webpack 4 bundles wrong javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I'm building an SSR Vue project, and I'm using webpack to bundle my files. The bundled file for the server works fine but the client one shows an error on the console and the code does not work.

I use these scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=serve webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.client.js --open --inline --hot",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev && npm run build-client && npm run build-server",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod && npm run build-client && npm run build-server",
    "build-serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev npm run build-server && npm run build-client && node server.js",
    "build-client": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.client.js --progress --bail",
    "build-server": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.server.js --progress --bail"
  }
```

and these are the webpack related packages:

```
"webpack": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
```

The weird thing is when using `webpack-dev-server`, the code works fine. Also when bundling the server file, it shows the results fine. But when using the client bundled file, it's not working.

and here is the error:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

webpack.client.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var base = require('./webpack.config')

base.resolve.modules = (base.resolve.modules || []).concat([

])
base.plugins = (base.plugins || []).concat([
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    isServer: false
  })
])

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod') {
  base.plugins = (base.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      }
    })
  ]);
}

module.exports = merge(base, {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/entry/client-entry.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'assets/build-client.js?[hash]',
  }

});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/styles.css');


module.exports = {
  // devtool: "source-map",
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/, // avoid webpack shimming process
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   loader: 'babel-loader',
      //   exclude: [/node_modules/, 'src/pages', 'src/components', 'src/layouts']
      // },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'assets/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(en|zh-tw)$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev')
        }
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: 'vendor'
    // }),
    // generate output HTML
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'src',
      'node_modules',
    ],
    alias: {
      '_': 'lodash',
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue',
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
    }
  },
  devServer: {//this handles the webpack router
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'serve') {

  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './assets', to: 'assets'},
      {from: './index.html'},
      {from: './index.server.html'}
    ])
  ])
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod') {
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: could you share your `webpack.client.js` configuration?

Comment: @salahudin: [Open a new issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues) and provide a little repo which reproduces the error above

Comment: @JoãoMenighin please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `CopyWebpackPlugin` plugin messes everything up. I don't know why but when I removed it, everything worked. Thanks.